# How do you get flex-column to work on iOS Safari?

Tags: css, ios, flexbox, safari

[On the left is a google pixel and on the right is a screenshot from my iphone.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Su1i4.jpg)

I'm having issues getting flex column to work on Safari on iOS. The elements overflow outside of the wrapper and they're also displayed as a row. I used a friend's mac and inspected the elements on safari and there were no issues when I opened up the site in responsive design mode. But on the phone the elements don't get displayed correctly. This is how the css looks for the wrapper displaying the skills.

```
.toolsWrapper {
grid-area: tools;
width: 100%;
height: 80%;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
position: relative;
flex-flow: column wrap;
justify-content: flex-start;
flex-direction: column;
flex-wrap: wrap;
align-items: flex-start;
align-content: flex-start;
}
```

It used to be a lot simpler, but I've added a lot to it to tryto get the flex direction working the right way on ios. Is there anything else I can add to get this to work on mobile?

Comment: looks like you might have forgotten : `-webkit-flex-flow:column wrap` ?

Comment: Thanks I'll try this.

Comment: It still didn't help.